# What do I have to do if I want to use the outer declaration only and not the inner declaration?

Tags: c++

For example

```
int main() {
int test = 1;
while(something) {
int test =1;
} 
}
```

Now I want to declare int test only once and not declared in the loop again, but I want the line of declaration in the loop also. I cannot remove it. How can I make the program use only the declaration made in the main function and not one made inside the loop.

Comment: You have overloaded that identifier and the outer one is hidden within the scope of your `while` loop.  The correct solution is to choose a different identifier for the variable.

Comment: I as mentioned want it to be inside and outside both but it should be using the outer declaration for some reasons. Is it possible?

Comment: No.  Why do you want this?  Whatever your reasons for wanting this, I'm going to assert that you need to adjust your thinking and explain what actual problem you're trying to solve instead of the (anti)solution you've chosen to solve it with.

Comment: @vrindavan You can't. The accepted answer to the duplicate question tells you why not.

Comment: *"How can I make the program use [...] not one made inside the loop."* -- Why do have a declaration inside the loop when your intent is to never use it? Drop the unused baggage, and the problem disappears.

Comment: What you claim you want to do can't be done. However, perhaps you've misunderstood the constraints, or are not describing what effect you actually want. Please edit  the question to clarify that.